# C# Windows Forms How to recognize what component Mouse is clicking on with MouseDown

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

i have a simple function that swaps Components around in my windows form

```
private void SwapPictures(PictureBox firstBox, PictureBox secondBox)
    {
        Image swap = firstBox.Image;
        firstBox.Image = secondBox.Image;
        secondBox.Image = swap;
    }
```

and i want to have a MouseDown and MouseUp implementation which calls my function with the respective PictureBoxes. My question is, how do i get the information which pictureBox im am clicking and releasing on?

Comment: Pass it as an argument (could be the Name, or even the PictureBox itself), then check in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast `object sender` to figure out which PictureBox was clicked.

```
private void PictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    // Check which pictureBox it is
    // Call your function
}
```